# Can you notate a function as an argument of another function?

Tags: functions, notation, research

So I'm writing a research paper. It's a computer science paper and I have written the following expression for calculating the average similarity of a set of images:
\begin{equation}
 \alpha(X) =  \sum_{\{x_1,x_2\} \in [X]^2} \frac{f(x_1,x_2)}{\vert[X]^2\vert}
\end{equation}

where $\alpha(X)$ iterates through all pairs within set of images $X$, and $f(x_1,x_2)$ is a measure of similarity between the pairs.

I'm trying to demonstrate that $f(x_1,x_2)$ can be either a computational measure of similarity (using some computer vision technique for example), or a human inputted one.

Would it be appropriate to demonstrate this with the following notation
\begin{align}
 \alpha(X,f) &=  \sum_{\{x_1,x_2\} \in [X]^2} \frac{f(x_1,x_2)}{\vert[X]^2\vert} \\
\end{align}

so that when I refer to the computational or human version I can write $\alpha(X,f^\mathit{comp})$ or $\alpha(X,f^\mathit{hum})$ respectively?

Comment: Sure, why not? That kind of thing gets done all the time. As long as you don't do something like $\alpha(X,f(x_1,x_2))$, then it should be fine.

Comment: As you can see the formula on the RHS depend from $f$, so it will be useful use the notation $\alpha (X,f)$.(obviously if  $f$ is not  fixed, this has more sense).

Comment: It's fine.  You could also use something like $\alpha_f(X)$ if you want to think of $f$ more as a "parameter" than an input.